# Display specific season name when user input month

Tags: javascript

Hello I am new to JavaScript I am trying to get season name when user enters a month name. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const takeInput = prompt("Enter the Season Name : ");
let seasons = {
  summer: ["may", "june", "july"],
  winter: ["november", "december", "january"],
};
takeInput.toLowerCase();

switch (takeInput) {
  case "summer":
    if (takeInput === seasons.summer) {
      console.log("summer");
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the season name based on the month, or the months based on the season? Your code asks for the "*Season Name*" while your question asks for a "*specific season name when user input month*"

Answer (score 1):

```js
takeInput === seasons.summer
```

Here you're checking if the takeInput is equals to seasons.summer but the fact is that the takeInput is a `string` whereas `seasons.summer` is an array.

Then it will always return `false`

---

You're also combining a `switch` with and `if`. This is the wrong way of doing it. In fact, the switch will be equivalent to an `if/else if/else`.

For example :

```js
const number = 1;
switch(number){
   case "1":
      console.log("odd")
      break;
   case "2":
      console.log("even")
      break;
   default:
      console.log('something else')
      break;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
const number = 1;
if(number === 1){
  console.log("odd")
} else if (number === 2){
  console.log("even")
} else {
  console.log('something else')
}
```

---

In your case, i thing you're looking for this :

```js
const takeInput = prompt("Enter the Season Name : ");
let seasons = {
  summer: ["may", "june", "july"],
  winter: ["november", "december", "january"],
};

switch (takeInput.toLowerCase()) {
  case "summer":
    console.log("summers");
    console.log("month", seasons.summer)
    break;
}
```

Note : If you want to find the season by month. You can do it like this :

```js
const takeInput = prompt("Enter the Month Name : ");
let seasons = {
  summer: ["may", "june", "july"],
  winter: ["november", "december", "january"],
};

Object.entries(seasons).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if(value.includes(takeInput.toLowerCase())) console.log(key)
})
```

Comment: The `takeInput.toLowerCase();` line returns a value that isn't used. It should probably be appended to the `prompt()` call (less code), or changed to set `takeInput` equal to the returned lower case value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//instead of 
   if (takeInput === seasons.summer) {
     console.log("summer");
    }
    //do this:
   if(seasons.summer.find(season => season === takeInput)){
     console.log("summer")
   }
```